# reload all files when running python script from IPython

Tags: python, module, ipython

when I run scripts from IPython using:

```
%run script.py
```

and edit the script or files that it imports outside of IPython, it doesn't get updated. I tried to use `autoreload` to make IPython reload all scripts:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 3
```

this does not work either. there's always left over "old state" that makes it so running `%run script.py` is not identical to going to the shell and typing `python script.py`. the latter loads the latest files from scratch and the former does not. is there a way to make IPython run a script just like from the shell?